# how to rectify error 1d returned 1 exit status, c

Tags: c

I wanted to know why I get the "error 1d returned 1 exit status" for this basic code in my Codeblocks ide.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("This is the first statement \n");
    printf("This is the second statement \n");
    printf("This is the third statement \n");
    printf("This is the third statement \n");
    goto end;
    printf("This is the fourth statement \n");
    end: printf("This is th fifth statement \n");
}
```

Comment: Probably because your `main()` doesn't return anything meaningful. And process exit code becomes undefined. Declare `main()` in proper way and put `return 0;` statement at the end.

Comment: There is no need of **return 0** . Since C99 is implicit.

Comment: Try changing `main()` to `int main(void)`

Comment: @Michi C99 also requires you to specify the return type of functions, which wasn't done here. So the code above is probably compiled as C89, where `main` doesn't return 0 by default.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what return value `main` should have. So it defaults to an `int`. But you didn't provide any `return` statement.